# fail to call a webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, asp-classic

I was given this structure of a webservice that i need to call to.
the ws name is Set_Details i got it right so that cant cause the error.
I cannot figure out how to solve this.
when i call it i got error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Set_Details Web Service method name is not valid. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

*i changed the real url paths to fake address so please ignore the urls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Set_Details xmlns="http://ws.blobobobo.uk/WebService/">
      <Details>
        <Number>int</Number>
        <Category>string</Category>
      </Details>
      <LoginID>string</LoginID>
      <LoginPassword>string</LoginPassword>
    </Set_Details>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

this is my code where i call a class webservice

```
  dim ws
      set ws = new webservice
      ws.url = mainip
      ws.method = "Set_OrderDetails"

      ws.parameters.Add "Number", "6166""
      ws.parameters.Add "Category", "ffff"

      ws.parameters.Add "LoginID", "ex10"
      ws.parameters.Add "LoginPassword", "ex20"


    ws.execute


    response.write ws.response
set ws = nothing
```

this is my class who represent the webservice

```
class WebService
    public Url
    public Method
    public Response
    public Parameters

    public function execute()
        dim xmlhttp

        Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        xmlhttp.open "POST", Url & "/" & Method, false
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        xmlhttp.send Parameters.toString
        response = xmlhttp.responseText
        set xmlhttp = nothing
    end function

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set Parameters = new wsParameters
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Set Parameters = Nothing
    End Sub

end class

class wsParameters
    public mCol

    public function toString()
        dim nItem
        dim buffer

        buffer = ""
        for nItem = 1 to Count
            buffer = buffer & Item(nItem).toString & "&"
        next
        if right(buffer,1)="&" then
            buffer = left(buffer,len(buffer)-1)
        end if
        toString = buffer   
    end function


    public sub Clear
        set mcol = nothing 
        Set mCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
    end sub

    public sub Add(pKey,pValue)
        dim newParameter

        set newParameter = new wsParameter
        newParameter.Key = pKey
        newParameter.Value = pValue
        mCol.Add mCol.count+1, newParameter

        set newParameter = nothing
    end sub

    public function Item(nKey)
        set Item=mCol.Item(nKey)
    end function

    public function ExistsXKey(pKey)
        dim nItem

        for nItem = 1 to mcol.count
            if mCol.Item(nItem).key = pKey then
                ExistsXKeyword = true
                exit for
            end if
        next
    end function

    public sub Remove(nKey)
        mCol.Remove(nKey)
    end sub

    public function Count()
        Count=mCol.count
    end function

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set mCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        Set mCol = Nothing
    End Sub
end class

class wsParameter
    public Key
    public Value

    public function toString()
        toString = Key & "=" & Value
    end function
end class


Dim ip
mainip="http://ws.bloblobo.uk/WebServices/ws.asmx"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling your SOAP web service method by doing a raw HTTP POST you should be constructing and sending the whole request as described by the web service. i.e. you need to send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Set_Details xmlns="http://ws.blobobobo.uk/WebService/">
      <Details>
        <Number>6166</Number>
        <Category>ffff</Category>
      </Details>
      <LoginID>ex10</LoginID>
      <LoginPassword>ex20</LoginPassword>
    </Set_Details>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

At the moment you're just POSTing:

```
Number=6166&Category=ffff&LoginID=ex10&LoginPassword=ex20
```

The web service plumbing has no idea what to do with that.

Your web service method also accepts a complex type, `Details`, so you have to send the request as a HTTP POST and with the full fat request (envelope, body etc).

You'll also need to set `SOAPAction` HTTP header in the request as well e.g.:

```
SOAPAction: "http://ws.blobobobo.uk/WebService/Set_Details"
```

**Updated:**

Here's a fully worked example:

```
<%
result = Set_Details(6166, "ffff", "ex10", "ex20")
Response.Write result

Function Set_Details(number, category, loginID, loginPassword)

  Dim request, doc, xmlHttp, url
  url = "http://ws.bloblobo.uk/WebServices/ws.asmx"

  request = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" & _
    "  <soap:Body>" & _
    "    <Set_Details xmlns='http://ws.blobobobo.uk/WebService/'>" & _
    "      <Details>" & _
    "        <Number>" & number  & "</Number>" & _
    "        <Category>" & category & "</Category>" & _
    "      </Details>" & _
    "      <LoginID>" & loginID & "</LoginID>" & _
    "      <LoginPassword>" & loginPassword & "</LoginPassword>" & _
    "    </Set_Details>" & _
    "  </soap:Body>" & _
    "</soap:Envelope>"

  Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  xmlHttp.open "POST", url, False
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", _
          """http://ws.blobobobo.uk/WebService/Set_Details"""

  xmlHttp.send request

  Set response = xmlHttp.responseXML

  '' The presumption here is that you get some kind of result back. 
  '' The example here assumes that the `Set_Details` method returns a simple type 
  '' such as a string, number or boolean
  result = response.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Set_DetailsResult").text

  Set_Details = result

End Function

%>
```

Finally never use `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` to make HTTP requests, it's not intended for use with ASP or server side applications, use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` instead.

Comment: ok i understand now but have no idea how to do this with my current code structure - is it possiable or do i need to change all class?

Comment: Do not build XML using string concatenation.  Use an XML DOM to create XML.  This will ensure correct encoding if incoming data contain characters such as `<` and `&`.  It will also ensure well-formedness of the XML.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - indeed. My answer is purely to demonstrate how to get the basics working, i.e. how to call a SOAP Web Service that accepts a complex type from classic ASP/VBScript; adding another 10 line of XML DOM fiddling would just obfuscate the answer.